Docker desktop version 4.29 socket mount permission problem
In v4.29 docker introduced socket mount permissions in ECI which is a business feature. Since then I cannot connect to a 3rd party socket (without paid plan). Have you guys encountered the same issue? I found open issues about it, but none of them has a working solution.
Anyway, it works fine with =< v4.28, but the fact that I can't update my version is frustrating.
I tried to grant permissions for /docker.sock, modify the docker engine configuration file, but no success.
Thank you for your answers!
For example I was able to call AWS cognito before (v4.28), now it's  Failed to fetch https://cognito -> TLSSocket.socketErrorListener

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

FYI disabling ipv6 in my container solved this particular problem.
sysctls:       - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
